# Is there anyway I can use if else inside ruby case..end

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

```
case search_term
when 'a'
  ptr = 0
when 'b'
  ptr = 1
when 'c' 
  ptr = 2
else
  ptr = 99
end

if location = 'xyz' and search_term = 'c'
ptr = 0
end
```

Is there any way to include the if above in the case statement?

Answer (score 7):

```
ptr = case search_term
when 'a'
   0
when 'b'
   1
when 'c' 
  if location == 'xyz' then  #note the ==
    0 
  else 
    2
  end 
else
  99
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The `case` construct is not normally used for complex logic. While you could find a solution that would work (like the answer by @steenslag), this path leads to trouble as conditions become more complex. A `case` statement with three or four branches is workable but already a bit of a code smell. More than that becomes problematic. Putting conditionals in `when` branches compounds the problem.

You might consider using small methods to break things up into separate responsibilities. This will make your code easier to understand, extend, and modify in the future.

```
def pointer # Ruby convention is to use real words where practical
  special_condition? ? 0 : pointer_base
end

def special_condition?
  location == 'xyz' && search_term == 'c'
end

def pointer_base
  search_term_map[search_term] || 99
end

def search_term_map
  ('a'..'c').zip(0..2).to_h # This could just as easily be ('a'..'z').zip(0..25).to_h
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternary operator inside the when-clause:

```
case search_term
when 'a'
  ptr = 0
when 'b'
  ptr = 1
when 'c' 
  ptr = location == 'xyz' ? 0 : 2
else
  ptr = 99
end
```

Two remarks:

- See the `==` to compare (`=` is an assignment)

Comment: This does not produce the same result as OP's logic. If `location == 'xyz'` this will result in `ptr` not being set to anything.

Comment: @moveson You are right, just missed the complete logic. I modified the code.

Answer (score 0):

This would be another possibility :

```
ptr = (location == 'xyz') ? 0 : 2
```

Brackets are not needed, but I find it more readable this way.

Answer (score 0):

If I was writing it tersely I'd use:

```
ptr = case search_term
      when 'a'
        0
      when 'b'
        1
      when 'c' 
        location == 'xyz' ? 0 : 2
      else
        99
      end
```

Ternary statements aren't really recommended though many languages allow them, primarily because too many people don't understand how to use them, or use them safely/maintainably.

Alternately it could be written:

```
ptr = case search_term
      when 'a'
        0
      when 'b'
        1
      when 'c' 
        if location == 'xyz' 
          0 
        else
          2
        end
      else
        99
      end
```

If you really want to have fun you could take advantage of `Hash.new`'s ability to return a default value:

```
Hash.new(99).merge(
  'a' => 0,
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => location == 'xyz' ? 0 : 2
)[search_term]
```

Testing them:

```
search_term = 'a'
location = 'xyz'

ptr = case search_term
      when 'a'
        0
      when 'b'
        1
      when 'c' 
        if location == 'xyz' 
          0 
        else
          2
        end
      else
        99
      end
ptr  # => 0

Hash.new(99).merge(
  'a' => 0,
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => location == 'xyz' ? 0 : 2
)[search_term]  # => 0
```

---

```
search_term = 'b'
location = 'xyz'

ptr = case search_term
      when 'a'
        0
      when 'b'
        1
      when 'c' 
        if location == 'xyz' 
          0 
        else
          2
        end
      else
        99
      end
ptr  # => 1

Hash.new(99).merge(
  'a' => 0,
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => location == 'xyz' ? 0 : 2
)[search_term]  # => 1
```

---

```
search_term = 'c'
location = 'xyz'

ptr = case search_term
      when 'a'
        0
      when 'b'
        1
      when 'c' 
        if location == 'xyz' 
          0 
        else
          2
        end
      else
        99
      end
ptr  # => 0

Hash.new(99).merge(
  'a' => 0,
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => location == 'xyz' ? 0 : 2
)[search_term]  # => 0
```

---

```
search_term = 'c'
location = 'abc'

ptr = case search_term
      when 'a'
        0
      when 'b'
        1
      when 'c' 
        if location == 'xyz' 
          0 
        else
          2
        end
      else
        99
      end
ptr  # => 2

Hash.new(99).merge(
  'a' => 0,
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => location == 'xyz' ? 0 : 2
)[search_term]  # => 2
```

---

```
search_term = 'z'
location = 'xyz'

ptr = case search_term
      when 'a'
        0
      when 'b'
        1
      when 'c' 
        if location == 'xyz' 
          0 
        else
          2
        end
      else
        99
      end
ptr  # => 99

Hash.new(99).merge(
  'a' => 0,
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => location == 'xyz' ? 0 : 2
)[search_term]  # => 99
```

Defining the hash on the fly is OK if you're not in a long loop or iterating over a lot of values for `search_term` or there's not a lot of key/value pairs being merged. Normally I'd use the first style for defining it.